# Custom parameters on knockout click binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm currently trying to call a function with a custom parameter, however I'm unable to access the parameter, and I get back an `observable()` object instead. Basically what I'm trying to do is to retrieve the index of that specific element in the list. Could someone point me in the right direction on how I could do so?

HTML:

```
<div id="formula">
  <b>Formula</b><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: formula -->
      <span data-bind="text: $data, attr: {name: $index}, click: $parent.convert.bind($data,$index)"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ListModel = function(formula) {
  var self = this;
  self.formula = ko.observableArray(formula);
  self.convert = function(index) {
    alert(index); //this should show the index of the clicked element
  }
};

listModel = new ListModel(formula);
ko.applyBindings(listModel);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be $parent.convert.bind($data,$index())

```
<div id="formula">
  <b>Formula</b><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: formula -->
      <span data-bind="text: $data, attr: {name: $index}, click: $parent.convert.bind($data,$index())"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/erovah/5/edit#source)

Comment: Got it thanks! Why does the index go into the first argument, and the data into the second argument?

Comment: First parameter will be used for 'this' pointer in your convert method. if you pass $parent.convert.bind(5,$index()) alert(this) will show 5 in the message box. BW you can use binding like this <div data-bind="foreach: formula">

Comment: I see. Yup I know about the div binding, but I wanted the array to be shown inside a single div.